# global ajax handler not working

Tags: jquery, css, ajax

So this is really a two-part question: why isn't it working, and should I even bother?

I have an ajax application that uses a lot of jquery's .load() and .get(). In my global js file I've added these lines to test jQuery's global ajaxComlete function:

```
$('body').ajaxComplete(function(e){
    alert();
});
```

I'm not getting any alerts when the ajax runs throughout the application. Does anyone know why?

The reason I want this is because I have a lot of styles that are applied through class names, and every ajax load essentially clears the old classes and brings in new classes. This removes my styling. So I have a global function called styleForm() that reapplys all my styles. I call this function in every individual ajax callback. ie:

```
$.get('source.cfm',funcion(){
    styleForm();
});
```

I know having this global ajax function will produce what most would probably consider 'clearner' code. But would it impact the performance much? If so, I don't want to do that. If not, then I'd like to get this working.

Comment: "The reason I want this is because I have a lot of styles that are applied through class names, and every ajax load essentially clears the old classes and brings in new classes. This removes my styling." Use CSS, that's **what it's for**.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist The DOM elements are removed and re-added. Styling a DOM element with css, this is no problem. Styling a DOM element with a classname using css, the style is not re-added.

Comment: Sounds like you're doing something wrong, then. The styling from the CSS declaration will apply even if the class is added to the element after the page has loaded or new elements with that class are added to the DOM.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist You're right. I just checked and my styling was applied to the div which contained an <a> that I wanted to style. The div was styled, but the <a> wasn't. So, it just looked as if the style wasn't re-applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried binding the ajaxComplete to `$(document)`?

In our code we use `$.ajaxSetup({})`, `$(document).ajaxStart(function(){})` and `$(document).ajaxStop(function(){})`.

The reason you need to use `$(document)`:

`$.get` is basically shorthand for `$.ajax` which will will trigger the ajax events (`.ajaxComplete`, `.ajaxError`, etc.) on document.

`$('body').ajaxComplete` will only trigger if you have bound an ajax event to it or a lower dom element. Usually this means something like `$('<header>').load('http://www.example.com');`

Comment: $(document) appears to work. Can you tell me why this is different than using $('body)?